# Hplip, succesful driver download but then fails to get the driver

Tags: drivers, printing, hp

I've been using different Ubuntu distros all over the last 10 years (Ubuntu, Xubuntu, Kubuntu, mint) at least.
Never asked for help once, I've always found the solutions to my problems online but this time, the fail-loop my distro went into.... this sounds a lot like a windows fail loop. Never seen a stupid fail like this one on Linux... thus I' m asking for help since I really feel like formatting my HD and quit Ubuntu for good. I'm using Kubuntu 18.04. I have a hp printer (just to be clear: this printer worked fine on Kubuntu and mint 14.04 and Kubuntu 16.04) and 18.04 came with hplip already installed. I thought this was great. The printer was able to scan with sane but there was no way of printing. I removed default hplip and installed the latest 3.19.1.
When I go get the proprietary drivers I get a "successful installation" message and right after that I get a message telling me that the driver was not installed !!!

[image: successful installation]

[image: Failure getting the drivers]

The Gui asks me to run the driver installation as normal user and I did that but then during the process root pw is required...
is there a kind of new security center in new Ubuntu distros blocking users action like windows uac or mac OS security app?
Because I can't think of any other reason creating such a stupid fail-loop.

update, I removed 3.19 and installed hplip 3.18. I tried to download the plugin in interactive mode. Looked like it worked but after restart the device is still missing its plugin. during plugin installation I get a warning that the security key was not found for the plugin but went on installing wihtout security key. This procedure has always worked on previous distros.
I tried to manually download the plugin from hp without any success.
I looked for the plugin in hplip install folder. I found this file

hp-deskjet_1120-hpijs.ppd
this looks like the right plugin but when I try to manually install the plugin the app looks for a *.run file!!!
[manual installation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XP4jf.png)

https://developers.hp.com/hp-linux-imaging-and-printing/plugins
here you can find the plugin download files (all plugins)
and the god****d .asc file needed for authorising.
I'll try to do everything manually... let's see if it works

update the plugin installation is definetly broken.
I'm manually giving "hp-plugin" app the .run file it needs. I got the Key/ authorizing file but the app wants to download it from hp server. The download fails. I don't know whether the settings app fails to create the device because it misses authorization or it just can't install the plugin properly. All I know is that hplip is broken for my printer and I need my printer for working.

update, with hplip 3.18.10 I managed to succesfully install proprietary drivers.
Both device manager and kubuntu printing app are seeing the printer. neither of those app can print a test page succesfully.
Something is blocking my printer. My printer print just fine by itself. I've already printed a test page using the printer internal configuration utility. 
[printer stopped](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bwpr4.png)

Answer (score 3):

The latest versions of hplib expect the sane libraries to be in different directories. This can be solved by adding symlinks to the actual locations of these libraries:

```
# create missing dirs
sudo mkdir /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu 
sudo mkdir /usr/lib64/x86_64-linux-gnu 

# make missing symlinks:
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/sane /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/sane
sudo ln -s /usr/lib64/x86_64-linux-gnu /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
sudo ln -s /usr/lib64/sane /usr/lib64/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane
```

After running the above commands, hp-setup should be able to install the plugin successfully.

Thanks to user zaskar_84's post here: https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/hplip-keeps-looping-at-plug-in-installation-4175647505/

Answer (score 1):

Install hplip-gui (sudo apt install hplip-gui) and try installing the printer via that. (It will be in the menu under hp toolbox or manager.) See if it works for you. The test pages don't always print correctly.  So try printing from a regular text file. see if it works.

Comment: tx for help, I tried your suggestion, but now the hp gui doesn't even let me add a printer. I can add a printer only through kde printer app. I'll try and purge both gui and hplip and reinstall 3.18.10. everything more recent looks kinda broken

Comment: I tried adding my cups log but apparently I can't. I tried printing from file. I always get the same filter error

Comment: That may be best.  You can try going to a web browser and typing in this address and try installing the printer throug cups.  (localhost:631) follow the instructions on the screen.

Comment: Well I had tried that seveal times but it says I don't have permission to add printer. Don't know how to log to cups but I tried printing with my printer and it returned same error. filter error.

Comment: I went through some guides talking about filter errors. I used hp-doctor and there was something weird in its log. it said i was using hplip 3.17 but I had removed that and I was using hplip 3.19. I already suspected there was something wrong when I saw 4 proprietary plugins in hplip plugin gui. I could use 3.17, 2 x 3.19 and one 3.18. Hp-doctor confirmed that the whole hplip installation is messed up.

Comment: I'm ready to reinstall the system but before doing that I launched the usb live 18.04 and the printer is broken there too. As I said 18.04 comes with hplip 3.17 already on board. Using the live usb I configured my printer. But when I tried printing I got same filter error.

Comment: So, I have the strong feeling hplip is broken on 18.04. Might not be broken for every printer but it surely is for my hp m1120n. I'm going to reinstall kubuntu from scratch and try to print but if it doesn't work I guess I'll move from kubuntu and try some other linux branch. I need to print and I bought this print years ago choosing it among the ubuntu supported one

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/b37wrypti0s0dsq/error_log?dl=0

Comment: here you can download my cups log file. All my tries from this morning

Comment: I believe this downgraded the version of the hplip-gui I had installed. Surprisingly it worked! Although I did install the *required plugin* but this time my printer started printing the pages!

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE!!!
DON'T remove default hplip and absolutely DON'T install a previous hplip.
It will brake your python dependencies and you will end up having a broken system with apt-get locked up for too many errors. I had to reinstall kubuntu 18.04 from scratch.
After a fresh install turn on your printer and launch hp-plugin from terminal

xxx-desktop:~$hp-plugin

Let the software get its plugin online.

DON'T install hplip gui. It will block plugin installation
My pc is working the right way now.

Comment: No, it won't. Not unless you have added a 3. party PPA for python, at least. `hplip-gui` wants to add a few python packages, but not any significant changes to the python environment.

Comment: What are you denying? Hplip downgrade breaking dependencies or the GUI blocking the plug-in installation? Because the first one you can try at your own risk but that's what happened to my previous installation ... No 3rd party whatsoever installed... I used discovery with default sources only. The second one, you can see my pictures... That's what happened using hp-lip GUI with default hp-lip installed

Comment: Ok wait, I backtraced what I did the first time in my mind and installing hp-gui isn't exactly what I did. The first time, after a fresh install I downloaded the latest hp-lip and upgraded the default one (I let the installer uninstall the default version first).  The installer installed hp-gui by default and I used the gui  to install the proprietary plugin without success as shown by my pictures. You might be right... It might not have been a gui fault but the latest hp-lip version itself might have been the cause

Answer (score 0):

Install `apparmor-utils`:

```
sudo apt-get install apparmor-utils
```

Run `hplip-plugin`:

```
sudo aa-disable /usr/share/hplip/plugin.py
```

Run as normal user, not as root:

```
hplip-plugin
```

Now the printer will get installed.